# How do I modify a text field for many entries at once?

Tags: 2007, document-library

I have a lot of files I've loaded into our Sharepoint system in a library.  I need to modify the same text field in the same way for all of them.  Is there a way to do this en masse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put your list into datasheet view (under Actions) copy the value you want to place into the field and then highlight whatever rows need to be updated and paste the value in.